# How to send data from backend to front end securely

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I am trying to find a way to send data from the back end to the front end securely.

My application is about posting images, and each post has a name, id, comments, etc..

The problem is that I want to prerender all my posts using pug, but also send all the data of those posts securely to the front end. I know that you can send data using the dataset attributes, but I don't want a client to see this data - I want it to be secure.

I just want to know if this is even possible, and if there is a secure way to implement this

E.g. Server sends data of 50 posts. Those 50 posts can be accessed in a front end js file, but cannot be accessed through the console in inspect element, or any other way.

Comment: To clarify, I am fairly new to node.js.

Comment: Nothing that is displayed on the front end should be considered secure in any language.

Comment: Fundamentally, there's no way to send data to the client while also preventing the client from seeing that data (that's essentially what you're asking here). The way this is generally done is to either return or not return data from the backend based on whatever authorization criteria you have.

Comment: The user has complete control over everything that runs in the front end. If their browser knows how to make use of some data that you sent to it, then the user can make use of that data too.

Comment: I heard somewhere that sending an Id that leads to a pattern is a security flaw, but would it be okay to create a totally random id for each post, and send that?

Comment: @Tidris it is always a good idea to tokenise ids as you can easily guess numbers that are sequential. It also means that if you have a data breach you can update the tokenised values especially if they are customer identifiers

Comment: Okay, I'll look into that

Answer (score -1):

Once the data hits the browser (e.g. front-end) it is available to the user. You can see the data in the Network tab of the dev tools in Chrome. I am not to sure what you mean by securing it in the front-end. It seems like you are trying to override browser functionality which is not possible. You can use javascript to a certain extend to stop people from getting the context menu on images etc, however, if a users looks hard enough it is easy to get the data that has been loaded.

Comment: So what do I do if I want send an id of a post? Should I create a another random id that can be used instead of the default ones from the database?

Comment: @Tidris I think we need more context as it is not clear what you are trying to do. You want to load 50 posts, but you don't want it accessible through the inspect element feature of the browser? What are the business rules here. Are users only allowed to see certain posts? Can it be managed server-side rather than on the client which is not really secure?